# visualstudio windows form designer file not updating windows7

Tags: windows, forms, visual-studio, windows-7, designer

I am trying to build a windows form  in VisualStudio 2010

I'm using some DevExpress components. And I have some in-house customized components.
(I am new to VisualStudio)
I start with a Windows Form, Convert to a DevExpress Xtra Form
I add a DateEdit component, a SimpleButton, a gridview

After a while the X.Designer.cs no longer changes!

The * no longer appears beside the file to indicate it has changed.

So when the build happens the newly added components are missing.

Some people have suggested my VisualStudio installation is corrupt and I should re-install

I am at a loss. There are 0 errors. 0 warnings. 0 messages. Why would this happen?
It is making development impossible.

I have seen some suggestions that deleting X.Designer.cs might help but that just empties out everything about the form!

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean you add code to add objects at run-time?